# XSLT Transformation incorrectly

Tags: xslt, xpath

Below is my XSLT and i need to consider all the "Table" tags from XML which has "XYZ" as text in it.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select= "Document"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//Table[.//TH[contains(text(), 'XYZ')]]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="spext:Converter(., 'true', './TR[5]', '2')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Below is my Input XML snippet. This will call method in c# for extracting specific tags from "Table" element passed by XSLT.

```
<Document>
  <Table>
    <TR>
      <TH>
        XYZ
      </TH>
      <TH>
        PQR
      </TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        Test data 1
      </TD>
      <TD>
        Test data 1
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </Table>
  <Part>
    <p>Hello World! This is some random text!</p>
  </Part>
  <Part>
    <Table>
      <TR>
        <TH>
          XYZ
        </TH>
        <TH>
          PQR
        </TH>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          Test data 3
        </TD>
        <TD>
          Test data 4
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </Table>
    <p>Random Test after!</p>
  </Part>
</Document>
```

My actual transformation output is below

```
<Root>
  <Table>
    <XYZ>Test data 1</XYZ>
    <PQR>Test data 2</PQR>
  </Table>Hello World! This is some random text!
  <Table>
    <XYZ>Test data 3</XYZ>
    <PQR>Test data 4</PQR>
  </Table>Random Test after!
</Root>
```

But desired output should be below

```
<Root>
  <XYZ>
       Test data 1
  </XYZ>
  <PQR>
       Test data 2
  </PQR>
  <XYZ>
       Test data 3
  </XYZ>
  <PQR>
       Test data 4
  </PQR>
</Root>
```

XSLT should only consider "Table" elements nothing else but here other tags text is also getting transformed and thus XML is not formed correctly.`enter code here`
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to post XSLT code using an extension function to complain the code doesn't work as intended without showing the implementation of the extension function and without explaining the task at hand in plain English. So post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem and explain exactly the criteria you want to implement. Also, which XSLT processor, which XSLT version do you use or can you use?

Answer (score 0):

A pure XSLT approach to transform the presented input sample to the desired output sample would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Document">
      <Root>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//Table[TR/TH[contains(., 'XYZ')]]/TR[TD]"/>
      </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TR">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TD"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TD">
      <xsl:param name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:element name="{normalize-space(../../TR[1]/TH[$pos])}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvL